# TeXShop does not like my .bib file

Tags: bibtex, texshop

I am trying to use BiBTeX, but I am getting the error message: *I couldn't open file name myBibliography.aux*

Here is my order of operations:

1. I created a .tex file called LatexTestPage.tex. Using TeXShop with the dropdown menu set to LaTeX, I clicked the Typeset button and the page compiles (although the citation appears as a ? when compiled).
   [image]

|

2. I created a .bib file called myBibliography.bib. This file is saved in the same folder as LatexTestPage.tex.

[image]

|

3. Using TeXShop with the dropdown menu set to BibTeX, I clicked the Typeset button.

[image]

|

4. I get the aforementioned error.

[image]

I am guessing there is a setting in TeXShop that I need to modify, but I do not have enough expertise to know what this setting is. Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: Try step 3 but with the `.tex` file opened, not the `.bib` one. `bibtex` should be run on `LatexTestPage.aux` which was created by `pdflatex`.

Comment: you are running bibtex  on a bib file, which can not work, you need to give it the name of your tex document so it reads the aux file

Comment: @Sigur Thank you for your response. I did step 3 with the .tex file opened. What do I do after that?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thank you for responding. When you write: "you need to give it the name of your tex document," what is the pronoun "it" referring to?

Comment: After you run bibtex with the tex file opened you have to run pdflatex (maybe twice) again to update the citations.

Comment: "it" refers to bibtex. you are forcing your editor to run `bibtex myBibliography`  which can not work, you need it to run `bibtex LaTeXTestPage` so that it can read `LaTeXTestPage.aux` and generate `LaTexTestPage.bbl`  your file listing shows that you have successfully done that previously as there is ` `LaTeXTestPage.bbl` already generated.

Comment: Please copy-paste code into your question as text. Images of code should never be included in posts. They make it more difficult for people to help you, harder for those with similar issues to find relevant posts and impossible for users who rely on screen-readers.

Comment: @Sigur and DavidCarlisle (I cannot notify 2 users at once with the @ sign) Thank you both for your help. With your suggestions, and with the assistance of the LaTeX Beginner's Guide (Kottwitz), I think I am starting to understand. The correct sequence is thus: 1. Typeset LatexTestPage with pdflatex 2. Typset LatexTestPage with bibtex 3. Typeset LatexTestPage twice with pdflatex. At no point is myBibliography ever typeset.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Please see above comment.

Comment: @cfr Thank you for this message, and for your admonition. I have benefited greatly from this site, and I am very open to heeding corrections from seasoned users. However, I do not understand your comment regarding "images of code should never be included." Why is it harmful to include photographs of code (as I did above) in a question where the confusion is related to the sequence of compilation, and not to anything in the code? (I am not trying to be critical, I just want to understand better.)

Comment: @Sam Because if I am blind and rely on screen-reading software, I have no way to decipher your images, whereas my software can read copy-pasted code.